# please someone check whats wrong with my code why I can not return count2?

Tags: java, return

```
public int count_two_char(String s, char c, char d){
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) == c){
            count = count + 1;
        }

        int count1 = 0;

        for(int i1 = 0; i1 < s.length(); i1++) {
            if(s.charAt(i1) == d){
                count1 = count1 + 1;
            }
            int count2 = count + count1;
        }
    }
    return count2;
```

The error is `count2 cannot be resolved to a variable` but I've already declared count2 as a variable,

Comment: count2 is not defined outside of your `for` loop so it isn't accessible to the `return`

Comment: Proper indentation would have made this clearer.

Comment: count2 only exists inside your 2nd for loop.

Answer (score 3):

you have to declare count2 before for loop,

```
    public int count_two_char(String s, char c, char d){
         int count = 0;
         for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
             if(s.charAt(i) == c){
                 count = count + 1;
     }

         int count1 = 0;
int count2;  // declare count2
         for(int i1=0; i1<s.length(); i1++){
             if(s.charAt(i1) == d){
                 count1 = count1 + 1;

             }
         count2 = count + count1;
         }
         }
        return count2;
```

try this code.

Comment: here is my test code @Test public void tests3(){ code.Solution s = new code.Solution(); String input = "llss"; int expected = 4; char c ='l'; char d ='s'; int actual = s.count_two_char(input, c, d); assertTrue("Expected was" +expected+"but the actual was" +actual , expected == actual); } the expect is 4 but it gave me a result 10. why??

Answer (score 3):

You initialized the count2 inside the for loop. count2 will not be remembered by compiler after the loop exist. declare the count2 above for loop like adjecent to count.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go my friend:

```
public int count_two_char(String s, char c, char d) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == c) {
            count = count + 1;
        }

    }
    int count1 = 0;
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < s.length(); i1++) {
        if (s.charAt(i1) == d) {
            count1 = count1 + 1;

        }
    }
    return count + count1;
}
```

And a little more elegant:

```
public int countTwoChars(String s, char c, char d) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == c || s.charAt(i) == d) {
            count += 1;
        }

    }
    return count;
}
```

The main problem in your original code was that the count2 was out of scope when trying to access it.

Comment: Please add some explanation. It would be more useful for the novice users!

Comment: it shows wrong when I use ur first code here is my  test code                       @Test public void tests3(){
  code.Solution s =  new code.Solution();
  String input = "llss";
  int expected = 4;
  char c ='l';
  char d ='s';
  int actual = s.count_two_char(input, c, d);
  assertTrue("Expected was" +expected+"but the actual was" +actual  ,  expected == actual);
 }
 the expect is 4 but it gave me a result 10. why??

Comment: No, it is 4. Just tried it now in my IDE and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Declare `count2` outside of `for` loop.

```
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
     for(int i1=0; i1<s.length(); i1++){
         if(s.charAt(i1) == d){
             count1 = count1 + 1;

         }
     count2 = count + count1;
     }
System.out.println("count2 "+count2);
```